# Should "unmeasurable" be used to describe missing data due to obstacles in obtaining measurements?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, lexicon

I am seeing the term "unmeasurable" used occasionally to describe measurements that could not be taken due to unusual circumstances. For example, audio qualities might not be measurable if there is a high degree of signal noise in the sample. Most dictionaries do not include this term, although "immeasurable" is included. However, I feel that "immeasurable" implies that something was so large or great that numbers could not be applied to it (e.g. immeasurable loss / damage / wealth). Is "unmeasurable" a term that I should add to my own lexicon?

Comment: There's nothing untoward in using 'unmeasuarble' for the situation you describe. As you correctly point out, 'immeasurable' means something quite different.

Comment: Some dictionaries do define unmeasurable: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmeasurable and
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unmeasurable

Answer (score 2):

Immeasurable implies that something is too large or extensive to measure. However, unmeasurable implies that something cannot be measured objectively.
The terms are subtly different in the usage and I suppose you should add it to your lexicon.

For better explanation, please read the following link:

http://libroediting.com/2012/08/24/unmeasurable-or-immeasurable/